# Wait until an event happens before doing anything else in JQuery

Tags: jquery, audio, media-player, html5-audio

I've asked a similar question but soon found it out of the topic, so let me explain my problem.

I have 5 audios. The goal is for each audio, play it 3 times.

Here is the code:

```
$('audio').each(function(index){
    playAudio(this.player, index);
});

function playAudio(audio, index){
        var loop = 3;

        // This will loop 3 times
        for(var i = 0; i < loop; i++){
            audio.play();

            $('.worship-items audio').eq(index).on('ended', function(){
                // When the song has ended, set the progress(current time) back to 0 seconds.
                audio.setCurrentTime(-1);
                audio.pause();
            });
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that Console is giving me this error:

> ***(15)*** Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().

Can someone help me out on this?

**Edit:** I was asked to add the html, so here it is:

```
<audio src="audio1.mp3"></audio>
<audio src="audio2.mp3"></audio>
<audio src="audio3.mp3"></audio>
<audio src="audio4.mp3"></audio>
<audio src="audio5.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: What is the `index` parameter for?

Comment: can you post html?

Comment: @Barmar the index parameter is so I can find that specific audio. Note: I'm also using the MediaPlayer.js plugin. I've also noticed I forgot to add `eq`. I'll make the edit.

Comment: In my answer I just pass the DOM element to the function, rather than the index. There's no need to use a selector when you have the element itself.

Comment: @Scaramouche I added the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop runs synchronously. You need to put the call to repeat in the `ended` handler.

Similarly, `.each()` runs synchronously. You need to start the next audio only when all the repeats of the previous one have concluded.

```
function playAudio(audios, index, loop, counter) {
    if (counter >= loop) {
        index++;
        if (index >= audios.length) {
            return;
        }
        playAudio(audios, index, loop, 0);
    }
    let audio = audios[index];
    audio.player.play();
    $(audio).off("ended").on("ended", function() {
        this.player.setCurrentTime(-1);
        playAudio(this, index, loop, counter + 1);
    });
});

playAudio($(".worship-items audio"), 0, 3, 0);
```

Comment: So how do I prevent it from playing the 5 audios simultaneously?

Comment: Okay, I'll test it

Comment: thanks a lot, I've been researching for 3 days with no success, you saved me an entire week!